# Apply filters on easy search results

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm using matteodem's [easy search](https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-easy-search) package. My search index:

```
EasySearch.createSearchIndex('userSuggestions', {
  'collection': User, 
  'use' : 'mongo-db',
  'limit': 5,
  'field': ['name', 'sex', 'profile.location', 'company'],
  query: function (searchString) {
    var query = EasySearch.getSearcher(this.use).defaultQuery(this, searchString);
        query['deleteReque'] = { $ne: true };
        return query;
    }
});
```

I'm using `esInput` and getting results

```
{{> esInput index=indexes class="side-search" id="dbsearch"}}
```

After getting the results, I'm giving the user option to filter, like `sex` M/F

How to perform these filters on results? Where I can perform these actions?

Comment: @Dandascalescu: Have some respect for the OP. A typo in the name of a package isn't a rebellious display of disrespect. It's just a typo.

Comment: That's fine guys.He added the link to resource for others to check.

Comment: Yea, but the edit reason is just rude.

Comment: yeah, I didn't saw that.

Comment: @Dandascalescu: So you're saying that if I can't spell his name right, I don't have respect for him.

Comment: @Cerbrus: are you following all my edits after the meta discussion? Nice to have a new fan! As for the initial quality of the post, oh well.